# dc.js - I'm facing issues rendering the dc.js dashboards in IE 11

Tags: dc.js

i have developed dashboards using dc. The dashboards are alligned and rendered well when i run it in Mozilla 52.4.0. 

 
Where as when i run the same html file in internet explorer 11, the dashboards not aligned (width, height of the svg) and also the pie/ donuts are not displayed.

 
Is that dc does not support using the IE browser or do i need to do some code change which will support using in IE.

 The reason i'm posting is that many of the users use IE rather than Chrome or Mozilla.

Comment: Should be supported! We test IE11. I just gave it a quick test - the examples for dc.js 3.0 won't work because they use d3-fetch, but the dc.js main page works fine (including donut charts) with dc.js 2.1. Can you describe the problem more exactly or provide an example?